# how to remove prefix in auto sql by using ignoreQualifiersAtRuntime="true"?

Tags: mybatis-generator

I try to remove the prefix in auto-generated sql in *mapper.xml

I user the tag  on ,but it didn't work. The prefix is like

```
SELECT a.id,a.permission_code,a.permission_name,b.group_id FROM public.admin_user
```

, I do want to remove "`public`." before table name.

```
<table schema="public" tableName="%">
      <generatedKey column="id" sqlStatement="JDBC"/>
       <property name="ignoreQualifiersAtRuntime" value="true"/>
 </table>
```

it shows :"table" content show matching `(property*,generatedKey?,domainObjectRenamingRule?,columnRenamingRule?,(columnOverride|ignoreColumn|ignoreColumnsByRegex)*)`"。

Comment: Are you sure this isn't working? The SELECT statement you are showing doesn't look like anything that would be created by MyBatis generator.

Answer (score 0):

Element `Property` should be put **before** `generatedKey`.
The message just tell you to mention the element sequence.